# First entry being skipped

Tags: c

When I run this it jumps past the "Enter first name" and goes straight to "Enter last name".

Example:

**Enter first name: Enter last name: Frank**

**The name is  Frank**

**Enter Phone:**

It won't let me put the First Name in. Ideas?

```
if( (fp=fopen("contacts","w")) == NULL )
{
printf( "Failed to open file contacts to write.\n" );
exit( 1 );
}


printf("Enter first name: ");
fgets(first, sizeof(first), stdin);

first[strlen(first) - 1] = '\0';

printf("Enter last name: ");
fgets(last, sizeof(last), stdin);

last[strlen(last) - 1] = '\0';

strcpy(list.name, first);
strcat(list.name, " ");
strcat(list.name, last);

printf("The name is %s\n", list.name);

printf("Enter Phone:");
fgets( line, sizeof( line ), stdin );
sscanf( line, "%s",&list.ph);
printf("You entered: %s", &list.ph);


printf("Enter Address:");
fgets( line, sizeof( line ), stdin );
sscanf( line, "%s", list.add );


printf("Enter Email Address:");
fgets( line, sizeof( line ), stdin );
sscanf( line, "%s", list.email );


printf("\n");


fprintf( fp, "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s", list.name, &list.ph, list.add, list.email );
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: As a general rule, you should post the smallest, compilable code that demonstrates the problem. Often, just doing *that* will make the real problem fairly obvious.

Comment: Note: when you declare these things, it is very important that you initialize them to 0. Also, make sure you call fgets with sizeof(first) - 1 so that you can't overflow the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you declared "first" as a char pointer, you must declare it as an array if you want that sizeof works otherwise you get the size of the pointer, regardless where it points

```
char first[100]; 
printf("Enter first name: ");
fgets(first, sizeof(first), stdin);
```

disclaimer: you didn't show the decl of any variables

Comment: Or simply pass the actual size of the buffer instead of using `sizeof` =)

Comment: although sizeof is more flexible in this (an array) cause you only need to keep track of the buffer if the size changes e.g char buf[100]; fgets(buf,100,stdin); is fragile for changes of buffer.

Comment: @AndersK That is why old school developers us `#define SMALL_BUFF 100` with `char first[SMALL_BUFF]` and `fgets(first, SMALL_BUFF, stdin)`. Change the value in define and it is changed everywhere it is used.

Answer (score 0):

There probably is some data (a wild `\n`, for example) in stdin. It is better to run your code under a debugger and see what happens.